# Generate extjs 4.2 app with sencha cmd, default theme name did not work

Tags: extjs, themes, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

i use flow command :

```
sencha -sdk D:\dev\ext\ext-4.2.1.883 generate app -t ext-theme-neptune msg .\
```

then i check the /.sencha/app/sencha.cfg file, the app.theme still like  this app.theme=ext-theme-classic,

and the bootstrap.css  still is @import 'ext/packages/ext-theme-classic/build/resources/ext-theme-classic-all.css'.

how could i change the app theme by using sencha cmd?

Comment: See this link: http://www.enovision.net/sencha-cmd-how-setup-ext-js-neptune-theme/. This is for Ext JS version 4. It is a step by step approach.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't tried generating an app which includes specifying a theme. Anyway, you can always change the `theme` of your app by editing the `app.theme=ext-theme-classic` to `app.theme=ext-theme-neptune` found on your project directory `.sencha/app/sencha.cfg`

then, execute

```
sencha app refresh
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe it will help smbd. For ExtJs 5 you only have to 
1) change in app.json:

```
"theme": "ext-theme-crisp-touch"
```

2) cmd:

```
sencha app build
```